install devops center for all users?
Can a system administrator install devops center for all users and then have those users create work items, and deploy them as long as the original installer user setup the project and connections?
I tried doing the above, but I get an error when assigning those users to the needed app permission sets. "Failure : entity type cannot be inserted: Permission Set Assignment"
I tried any combo of the following permission sets and I get the same error
including:

DevOps Center
DevOps Center Manager
DevOps Center Release Manager
sf_devops_InitializeEnvironments
sf_devops_NamedCredentials

The use case is that I want BA's to create work items that would be built by system admins

In theory, you should be able to utilise the Salesforce Limited Access - Free licenses if you have requested them from Salesforce, as per https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.devops_center_add_team_members.htm&type=5 and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.252.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/dev_hub_license.htm
